# Getting started with bundle DI in an OSGi environment

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix

I have been developing an application with Apache Felix as my OSGi runtime for a while and up until now progress has been great. However, I want to now adopt dependancy injection and the "default" mechanism with Apache Felix seems to be iPOJOs.

However, I've found that the documentation and tutorials around about Apache felix are too weak and I've not managed to get anywhere. So I am prepared to change, but first of all I'd better explain the (very simple) think I'm trying to do.

Given two bundles;

*Consumer bundle*

```
package bundles.consumer;

class Consumer implements BundleActivator{
    @Inject
    private Producer producer;

    public void bundleActivated(BundleContext con) {
        this.producer.getNextItem();
    }
}
```

*Producer Bundle*

```
package bundles.producer;

@Singleton
class Producer {
    public String getNextItem() {
        return "item x"; 
    }
}
```

I want the OSGi runtime to start up the Consumer bundle, realize that it needs a Producer to work, the framework then starts the Producer bundle and injects and instance into the Consumer. Simples. iPOJOs suggest that this is possible using annotations only (@Singleton, @Inject) or similar, but I simply can't get it to work. OSGi apparently has declarative services, but that means writing a lot of XML, which I *really* want to avoid.

Anywoo, I'm prepared to adapt JBoss, Equinox or alternative OSGi runtime and an alternative dependancy injection mechanism, be that Peaberry, Spring DM or something completly difference. I'm already using Maven.

What I'm asking, is can somebody create a Hello World using the Producer and Consumer idea to help me get started? I've really spent a tonne of time reading up and find the learning curve insurmountable!

---

edit, my attempt using SCR: http://tydus.net/codeExamples/mvnScr.tar

Comment: I agree with the answers, but want to clear up a misconception. iPOJO is not necessarily Felix's "default" DI framework, it's simply another project hosted at Apache. iPOJO works on Felix, Equinox, Knopflerfish etc. Also Declarative Service (DS) works on Felix, Equinox, Knopflerfish... so does Spring-DM... so does Blueprint. There is no need to change your OSGi container just because you cannot get iPOJO working.

Comment: Also, please describe why you couldn't get iPOJO working, and how exactly it failed. It *should* work, but you haven't given us enough information to suggest a fix.

Comment: Neil, I am aware of the situation in your first comment, forgive me if it was a little garbled in my original post. While I am more than willing to invest time in getting iPOJOs working, it would almost be going off topic here. I'm experimenting with SCR at the moment as per suggestions from other members. I did actually send your an email while looking for help, but appreciate you are probably too busy for a 1 on 1 tutorial! (although that would be great!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things to bear in mind; 1) your bundle will probably need some extra metadata for the dependency injection framework and 2) you'll need to deploy the DI framework's runtime.

Dependency injection is not part of core OSGi (i.e. the Felix framework) so you must first deploy the iPOJO bundle(s) before deploying your own.  Additionally you'll need to add the metadata required by IPOJO, google "maven-ipojo-plugin" for more info.

If you're looking for a container that is less bare-bones than Felix on it's own, then try [Karaf](http://karaf.apache.org) (it comes with lots of enterprise extras).

Personally, I like Declarative Services (so +1 Dmytro) as it's very simple and merely removes the boiler plate code from OSGi (remember to deploy [it](http://mirror.lividpenguin.com/pub/apache//felix/org.apache.felix.scr-1.6.0.jar) as well and provide component.xml in your bundle see [maven-scr-plugin](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-scr-plugin.html) for more info).

---

### EDIT

(In answer to comment and link to tarball below)

I moved the @Service annotation from Producer to ProducerImpl.

The generated SCR component.xml wasn't quite correct for the Consumer, by adding an unbind() method and changing the @Reference the following works:

```
//...
import static org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.ReferenceCardinality.MANDATORY_UNARY;
import static org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.ReferencePolicy.DYNAMIC;

//...
@Component
public class Consumer
{
    @Reference(policy = DYNAMIC, cardinality = MANDATORY_UNARY)
    private Producer producer;

    public void unbindProducer() {
        System.out.println("Producer unbound.");
        this.producer = null;
    }
//...
}
```

---

**Deploying Maven**

As you're using maven, install [Pax Url for maven](http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/paxurl/Mvn+Protocol), this way you can easily install bundles from local and remote repositories.

First get maven to download a version for you (pax-url-mvn version 1.3.5 is available) then install the file (or copy to Felix bundle dir)

```
-> install file:/YOUR_PATH_TO_MAVEN_REPO/.m2/repository/org/ops4j/pax/url/pax-url-mvn/1.3.5/pax-url-mvn-1.3.5.jar
Bundle ID: 7
-> start 7
DEBUG: WIRE: [7.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.net.ssl) -> [0]
DEBUG: WIRE: [7.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.parsers) -> [0]
DEBUG: WIRE: [7.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) -> [0]
DEBUG: WIRE: [7.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.cm)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) -> [2.0]
DEBUG: WIRE: [7.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.url)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) -> [0]
DEBUG: WIRE: [7.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.w3c.dom) -> [0]
DEBUG: WIRE: [7.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.xml.sax) -> [0]
->
```

You can now install your own bundles from your local repository with the mvn URL handler:

```
-> install mvn:com.examples/producer/1.0.1
Bundle ID: 10
-> start 10
-> install mvn:com.examples/consumer/1.0.1     
Bundle ID: 11
-> start 11
DEBUG: WIRE: [11.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.examples.producer)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) -> [10.0]
Producer bound.
Consumer activate
Aloha.
->
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The iPOJO runtime was installed and active and my bundles were being processed with the maven-ipojo-plugin (I manually checked). I really like Felix for being very lightweight and customizable, but thanks for the link to Karaf, I'll check it out. SCR and Declarative Services looks like a way to go, but at the moment I simply cannot get it to work and am receiving no error messages (see comment to Dymtro, above).

Comment: Felix is great but for experimenting Karaf gives you a nice full suite.   I'd be happy to look at any Declarative Service code.  Please post the generated OSGI-INF/component.xml and a simple service.

Comment: I don't have space to post it within this comment, here a URL to the project; http://tydus.net/codeExamples/mvnScr.tar

Comment: Thank you so very much for your time, that was a great help!

Comment: You're welcome, OSGi has a steep-ish learning curve but it's well worth the effort =)

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use Declarative Service because it's a OSGi Standard.

You can use Java Annotations to describe DS dependencies, services and components with [Maven SCR plugin](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-scr-plugin.html)

Regards,
Dmytro

Comment: +1 though it is better to use bnd annotations rather than Maven SCR plugin annotation, because they work outside of Maven (and inside Maven as well, of course!)

Comment: Thank you, Dmytro. I have been experimenting with SCR and got a little further than with iPOJOs, but got to state where apparently the dependencies for my bundles were "unsatisfied". The producer class has @Component, the consumer class has @Component and an @Reference field. When starting the bundles I received no error messages (checked `log` from the felix console). I also set ds.loglevel to 999, ds.showtraces=true, ds.showerrors=true, but still nothing. Would you be willing to post some example code for me? I can work out error messages, but this simply doesn't work and doesn't say why!

Comment: check here: http://blog.knowhowlab.org/2010/10/osgi-tutorial-4-ways-to-activate-code.html, http://felix.apache.org/site/scr-annotations.html and, of course, OSGi Spec (it contains some code samples)

Answer (score 0):

I've written a fragment for the Equinox Declarative Services bundle that allows you to mark up your classes with annoations that correspond to DS servicce XML elements; yes, it's a hack with its own limitations, but it's working good so far in projects with 90+ bundles. I could probably manage to clean it up, document and publish it this week if you are interested.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I would more prefer to use standard/published code simply because the documentation is more likely to be better. Any useful links to tutorials are welcomed.